# I need to unset terms from the drop down

Tags: 7

I'm writing a module to unset taxonomy terms using D6 `hook_form_alter()`. The object is to only present the current user terms which they have created themselves.

The trouble is that I don't know which variables to alter. I'm thinking it should be something like `$form['taxonomy']['2']['#options']`, but I cannot see a path in a DSM `print_r($form)`.

I have gone through hierarchical_select.module again and again, but can't work out whether I need to be amending the results of `$storage`, `$elements`, `#names`, `$hsid` or any of the other variables; I am not sure about which hook to use too.

I just need to know how to apply the results of this `db_query()` in my custom module code which you can see on http://pastebin.com/RbwKB0rt.

Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think I need more information.

In general, I believe you set the `#default_value` on your dependent form element to be the parent element, and also set the `#ajax` callback and wrapper on the parent. Check out the Ajax example and the form API reference.